# nameservers one domain one VPS and one VMCloud

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I 'had' just a single VPS with nameservers ns1 & ns2.mydomain.com. I've now taken a VMCloud package as I need space etc.

Ultimately I will carefully transfer all accounts from my VPS to Cloud but in the short term I'm running both.

In the new WHM on Cloud I have set hostname bla.domian nameservers as ns3 & ns4.mydomain.com with the two new ip addresses.

Question is do I need to do anything else - eg where mydomain.com is registered? I want  ns1 & 2 point to VPS and ns3 & 4 to point to Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The registrar that you registered "mydomain.com" at will/should allow you to register nameservers.  What that does is officially specify what nameservers your domain name uses - because whois must list nameservers before you query DNS (since you need to know what DNS servers are authoratative... and you can't store that in DNS since it's a chicken-egg issue).

So, go in to your registrar and register ns3 and ns4, then update your domain to use ns3 and ns4 instead of ns1 and ns2.  Once you confirm that your domain is now resolving to the new IP address and your nameserver information has propogated (depending on TTLs, can take up to a week for the whole Internet).

After that, you can go in to DNS and update the IP for ns1 and ns2 to that of ns3 and ns4.  Then go to your registrar (update the IP for ns1 and ns2 if it offers you the ability) and set your domain to use ns1 and ns2 again.  After propogation you can eventually get rid of ns3 and ns4.

Comment: It's a common misconception that WHOIS have anything to do with DNS resolution. WHOIS is a database for human administrative purposes ONLY.

Comment: Yes, however I wasn't going to confuse the poster - they don't need to know that the WHOIS info is just informative - just that it matters they have the proper nameservers registered as the authoratative nameservers at their registrar and not just updating the NS records for DNS.